# Unbound, exceptions to local-zone rules for specific subdomains and main domain

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a simple rule to point my `domain.tld` to a local address `192.168.0.205`. It takes everything; all subdomains `*.domain.tld` as well as the main domain itself.

```
    local-zone: "domain.tld." redirect
    local-data: "domain.tld. IN A 192.168.0.205"
```

I have my load balancer at `192.168.0.205` so for making requests working internally I need to do this. However, my mail server is located outside this network, so I need to make three exceptions to this; `smtp.domain.tld`, `imap.domain.tld` and `domain.tld` itself. I'd prefer if I just could make those slip through to the ISP's dns, but if that is not possible I can live with having to set their global ip's in my config.

How can I do this? I've tried using `transparent` instead of `redirect` but I cannot make it work like I want. I think one of the main problems is to handle the main domain without subdomain prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Use this style, multiple level wildcard subdomains:

```
local-zone: "sub.domain.tld."   redirect
local-data: "sub.domain.tld.  IN  A  222.222.222.222"

local-zone: "domain.tld."   redirect
local-data: "domain.tld.  IN  A   111.111.111.111"
```

Answer (score 3):

This configuration worked for me using Unbound v1.9.0:

```
server:
    # Resolve smtp and imap subdomains normally
    local-zone: "smtp.domain.tld" transparent
    local-zone: "imap.domain.tld" transparent

    # Redirect domain.tld to a machine on the LAN
    local-zone: "domain.tld" redirect
    local-data: "domain.tld 3600 IN A 192.168.0.205"
```

Note that the order of these statements matters. Write your rules from most specific to least specific.

Answer (score 0):

To make an MX record work, you can use the following construct.
Use transparent for the mail-server subdomain.
And add the MX record to the redirect part.

```
local-zone: "mail.domain.tld." transparent

local-zone: "domain.tld" redirect
local-data: "domain.tld IN A 192.168.0.205"
local-data: "domain.tld IN MX 0 mail.domain.tld."
```